# Truth value of this predicate

Tags: analysis, logic

Suppose I want to check the truth value of the predicate $\forall x \in A: x \geq 0$, where $A \subset \mathbb R$. If $A = \varnothing$, would the predicate be true or false?
I think it should be true, because we cannot find $x \in A$ such that $x \geq 0$ is false, but I'm not sure.

Comment: No, it will be True: $\forall x (x \in \emptyset \to x \ge 0)$. See [Vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA; Sorry, it was a typo I meant true instead of false. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: Note we can equivalently write your statement as $\neg \exists x \in A\ x < 0$ — is there an $x \in \varnothing$ with $x < 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be true vacuously. Like you said, since we can't find any $x$ such that $x\ge 0$ is false, it will be true.

Answer (score 1):

For any unary predicate $P$, we can formally prove $\forall a: [a \in \emptyset \implies P(a)]$ (see below). This statement will be true even if $P(a)$ is always false. The proof here makes use of both direct proof (line 9) and proof by contradiction (line 7). On lines 1-2, we define the empty set *null*.

(Screenshot from my proof checker)

[image]